# Override Javascript Function Expression

Tags: javascript, yui, alfresco-share, yahoo-api

I have a scenario where I want to override/modify the javascript function expression. This is how the function expression looks like.

```
var func_1 = function func_1(){
  // 300 lines of code
  var func_2 = function func_2(){
     // few lines of code
  };
};
```

I can access the above function in a different context and want to change the approach of func_2() and it should look like this.

```
var newfunc_1 = function func_1(){
  // 300 lines of code
  var newfunc_2 = function func_2(){
     // new lines of code
  };
};
```

How can I achieve this? I believe copy the whole function and modifying will be the worse option.

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the code in `func_1`?

Comment: you can't do it with the way it is written

Comment: @Mordred, That is my question. I can access the variable "func1". But want to know  whether I have the ability to modify that.

Comment: @epascarello, Thanks!!

Comment: It would probably be better to explain why you need that and what you want to achieve with that using a [mcve].

Comment: @shamran my question was whether you can alter/refactor the original `func_1`, or if this is a user script type scenario where you just want to change functionality after the fact and can't alter the code in the original JS file. This may seem like an obvious question, but it's impossible to tell exactly why you want to do this, or what your current JS programming ability is from the question as written, so it has to be asked.

Comment: @t.niese and Mordred, 
This the Alfresco Share client side UI code. Based on YUI javascript library.
What I want to achieve is that alter the code by extending the original file (It is a YUI class with several methods).
I can extend the original class like "YAHOO.extend(myClassName, originalClassName, {//methods...});"
And I can access the parent class method which is func_1 in the above example.
The func_1 is returned as an expression and this is called when the UI action is triggered.

Comment: @Mordred and t.niese,
As this is a complex code base, I couldn't dig to find the triggering point where the "func_2" is called. However I can confirm that the func_2 need to be modified in the subclass.

As a solution, I can either alter the original file or re-declare the "func_1" in the sub class if modifying "func_1" from the subclass is never possible.

Comment: If you point out me, exactly which Alfresco share JS and method you're trying to override. Already we've overidden some of the Share JS methods.